# Need to Copy Tags in a XML String

Tags: xml

I have an xml file that I need to modify on a daily basis. Something very simple written for bash or xmlstarlet..... or anything simple. The string below is just one of a thousand channels that need changed. So it must parse each line and copy site_id to xmltv_id. Thank you for helping me.

it creates this..

`channel update="i" site="merge-xmltv" site_id="citytoronto.ca" xmltv_id="CITY TV (Toronto ON) (CAN)">CITY TV (Toronto ON) (CAN)`

I need to copy the site_id value to xmltv_id value..

`channel update="i" site="merge-xmltv" site_id="citytoronto.ca" xmltv_id="citytoronto.ca">CITY TV (Toronto ON) (CAN)`

Answer (score 0):

This works

`sed -i 's/site_id="([^"])" xmltv_id="[^"]"/site_id="\1" xmltv_id="\1"/g' WebGrab++.config.xml`